# Add a string in middle of dynamic NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i have NSString, were the content of NSString is from a url. i want to add a word in between this NSString followed by a particular word. were this NSString will be changing constantly

for example:

i am getting a data like`" hi mac this is ios"`, this string may change constantly like this
`" hi ios this mac" or hi this is mac ios"`, etc.

i want to add a word like "hello" followed by "mac" always

```
" hi mac hello this is ios"
" hi ios this mac hello"
"hi this is mac hello ios"
```

how can i do this

Comment: Means you want to add "hello" always after "mac"?

Comment: yes exactly..i need the same

Comment: @PradeepKumar: you can use insertString:atIndex: ... see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Mac" withString:@"Mac Hello"];
```

Comment: i dont want to replace it but add to it

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Yourstring = [Yourstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"mac" withString:@"mac hello "];
```

Comment: i dont want to replace it, but add to it

Comment: @PradeepKumar: ultimately your requirement is fulfilled with this code.

Answer (score 0):

NSString *str = @"Hi Mac this is";

```
if ([str rangeOfString:@"mac" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
{
    int location = [str rangeOfString:@"mac" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location;

    NSMutableString *mstr = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:str] autorelease];
    NSString *strtemp = @"mac";

    [mstr replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(location, [strtemp length]) withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", strtemp, @"hello"]];

    NSLog(@"test  %@", mstr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to replace mac with mac hello, then you can do in this way

```
NSMutableString *string=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"hi mac this is ios"];
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"mac"];    
[string insertString:@" hello" atIndex:range.location+3];
NSLog(@"str=%@",string);
```

Output :

```
str=hi mac hello this is ios
```